# ASP.NET 6.0 [FromQuery] string is null when whitespace is passed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to figure why an optional query string value is null even if whitespace is passed.

```cs
[HttpGet("test")]
public string Search(string q = null)
{
  return q;
}

//OR

[HttpGet("test")]
public string Search([FromQuery] string q = null)
{
  return q;
}
```

Example outputs:

- `test?q=a` == `a`
- `test?q= a` ==  `a`
- `test?q=`  == `null`
- `test?q=+` == `null`
- `test?q=%20` == `null`
- `test?q=+ + %20 +` == `null`

I would expect null only if the query string was missing since it's optional and then all other values to be the given string with white space. I'm trying to allow searching for spaces and I can't get the query string to allow that. Any ideas?

Comment: I am just wondering why it makes a difference for you? What is the problem? is your code working? This is not a place for an abstract discussions about nothing. Pls tell what is your problem and you will be given an adise.

Comment: @Serge, as mentioned, I'm trying to allow a search with spaces and `null != ' '` so I can't translate this to a search that contains a space. For example, let's say I'm searching for book title that I know was entered incorrectly that had two spaces like `maze  runner`. I can't search for the two spaces because that equates to null. Null to me means the value wasn't entered. I need to know when whitespace was in the query string vs nothing there at all.

Comment: I just tested your examples and the most of them working properly (except ++ is ignored)

Comment: Thanks @Serge! I'll start with a minimal api and test it out. Perhaps something in the middleware is messing it up.